# ListView crash when scrolling up

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm having a little issue with a ListView. For sure it is something I'm doing wrong and I cannot find the answer, I'd like to know if someone could point my mistake and help me to fix it.

The thing is that I'm creating a ListView with two different layouts for the row. One is a row with only text and the other one is a layout with text and image. Only the four last values of the array with the data will be the ones using this second layout with the image.

The ListView is showing correctly when the activity is loaded, and the rows have correctly set the click actions. I can scroll down the list but when I scroll it up the app stops and the following error is raised:

```
05-05 12:30:46.574    1532-1532/com.xxx.xxx.app E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
05-05 12:30:46.574    1532-1532/com.xxx.xxx.app E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-05 12:30:46.578    1532-1532/com.xxx.xxx.app E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.xxx.xxx.app.LawyersActivity$LawyersAdapter.getView(LawyersActivity.java:246)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ListView.correctTooLow(ListView.java:1467)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:665)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5136)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onGenericMotionEvent(AbsListView.java:3804)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEventInternal(View.java:7801)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7782)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1824)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1777)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7775)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1824)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1777)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7775)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1824)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1777)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7775)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1824)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1777)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7775)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2076)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1525)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(Activity.java:2494)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:278)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2030)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at c
05-05 12:30:46.582    1532-1532/com.xxx.xxx.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxx.xxx.app, PID: 1532
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.xxx.xxx.app.LawyersActivity$LawyersAdapter.getView(LawyersActivity.java:246)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2240)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ListView.correctTooLow(ListView.java:1467)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:665)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5136)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onGenericMotionEvent(AbsListView.java:3804)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEventInternal(View.java:7801)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7782)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1824)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1777)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7775)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1824)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1777)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7775)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1824)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1777)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7775)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1824)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGenericPointerEvent(ViewGroup.java:1777)
        at android.view.View.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(View.java:7775)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2076)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1525)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(Activity.java:2494)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:278)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2030)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
        at         
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.and
```

The code I'm using for the custom adapter is as follow. The variable size has the count of the part of the array that have to be set with the first layout (all but the four last).

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.xxx.xxx.MESSAGE";
public final static String WEB_URL = "http://www.test.com";
public final static String CONTACT_EMAIL = "email@email.com";
public final static String EMAIL_SUBJECT = "Text";

ArrayList<Lawyer> lawyers = new ArrayList<Lawyer>();
String categorie = null;
int size;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    categorie = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lawyers);

    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
    try {
        pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

        InputStream in_s = getResources().getAssets().open("lawyers.xml");
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in_s, null);

        parseXML(parser);

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    size = lawyers.size();

    Lawyer auxLawer = new Lawyer();
    auxLawer.caseName = "Who are we?";
    auxLawer.icon = "icons_list_07";
    lawyers.add(auxLawer);

    auxLawer = new Lawyer();
    auxLawer.caseName = "Call now";
    auxLawer.icon = "icons_list_08";
    lawyers.add(auxLawer);

    auxLawer = new Lawyer();
    auxLawer.caseName = "Check our web";
    auxLawer.icon = "icons_list_09";
    lawyers.add(auxLawer);

    auxLawer = new Lawyer();
    auxLawer.caseName = "Text us";
    auxLawer.icon = "icons_list_10";
    lawyers.add(auxLawer);

    LawyersAdapter adapter = new LawyersAdapter(this);

    ListView lstOpciones = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewLawyers);
    lstOpciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    lstOpciones.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

            if (position < size) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LawyersActivity.this, CaseDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Lawyer", lawyers.get(position));
                LawyersActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            } else if (position == size) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LawyersActivity.this, MiAppActivity.class);
                LawyersActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
               } else if (position == (size + 1)) { //LLamar
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + R.string.phone_number));
                LawyersActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            } else if (position == (size + 2)) { //Web
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(WEB_URL));
                LawyersActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            } else if (position == (size + 3)) { //Email
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                        "mailto", CONTACT_EMAIL, null));
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, EMAIL_SUBJECT);
                LawyersActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar email..."));
            }

        }
    });
}

private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException {

    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    Lawyer currentLawyer = null;

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String name = null;
        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("lawyer")) {
                    currentLawyer = new Lawyer();
                } else if (currentLawyer != null) {
                    if (name.equals("categorie")) {
                        currentLawyer.categorie = parser.nextText();
                    } else if (name.equals("type")) {
                        currentLawyer.type = parser.nextText();
                    } else if (name.equals("case")) {
                        currentLawyer.caseName = parser.nextText();
                    } else if (name.equals("description")) {
                        currentLawyer.description = parser.nextText();
                    } else if (name.equals("advise")) {
                        currentLawyer.advise = parser.nextText();
                    } else if (name.equals("empresas")) {
                        currentLawyer.empresas = parser.nextText();
                    } else if (name.equals("trabajadores")) {
                        currentLawyer.trabajadores = parser.nextText();
                    }
                }

                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("lawyer") && currentLawyer != null){
                    if (currentLawyer.categorie.equalsIgnoreCase(categorie)) {
                        lawyers.add(currentLawyer);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lawyers, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    item.setVisible(false);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class LawyersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    Activity context;

    LawyersAdapter(Activity context){
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_lawyer, lawyers);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position < size) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View item = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        ViewHolderImage holderImage;

        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            if (item == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_lawyer, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.titulo = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.titleLawyer);

                item.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();
            }

            holder.titulo.setText(lawyers.get(position).caseName);
        } else {
            if (item == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_categories, null);
                holderImage = new ViewHolderImage();
                holderImage.titulo = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.titleCategory);
                holderImage.imagen = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.imageCategory);
            } else {
                holderImage = (ViewHolderImage) item.getTag();
            }
245
246            holderImage.titulo.setText(lawyers.get(position).caseName);
247            String uri = "drawable/" + lawyers.get(position).icon;

            int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

            Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

            holderImage.imagen.setImageDrawable(image);
        }

        return(item);
    }

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titulo;
}

static class ViewHolderImage {
    TextView titulo;
    ImageView imagen;
}
```

And the way I'm setting the adapter into the view is this:

```
LawyersAdapter adapter = new LawyersAdapter(this);
ListView lstOptions = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewLawyers);
lstOptions.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1: Included the full code of the activity.**

Comment: please specify line number 246 in LawyersAdapter.

Comment: Where are you initializing the size variable ? Also, the error seems to be in Line 246 of LawyersActivity. What does it contain ?

Comment: Check if your `context` is null in the adapter

Comment: I updated the code marking the line 246, which is this one:

    holderImage.titulo.setText(lawyers.get(position).caseName);

The context doesn't should be null as it works great with only one kind of layout.

About the size variable, it is defined this way:

size = lawyers.size();

It is the variable part of an array and after that I add the next four fields to the array. This four things are like ("who are we?", "Send us an email", "Call us"...) at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've been able to get a solution using the LayoutInflater. As I don't have too much experience with Android I think I've been messing up code implementations to achieve it.

This is the code of the adapter that is working for me now. I hope it could help to somebody else.

Thanks for your comments.

```
class LawyersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lawyer> {

    private final Context context;

    LawyersAdapter(Context context){
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_lawyer, lawyers);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position < size) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case 0:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_lawyer, null);
                    holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleLawyer);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_categories, null);
                    holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleCategory);
                    holder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageCategory);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(lawyers.get(position).caseName);

        if (type == 1) {
            String uri = "drawable/" + lawyers.get(position).icon;

            int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

            Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

            holder.image.setImageDrawable(image);
        }

        return convertView;

    }

}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    ImageView image;
}
```